# How make a multi client server using Bluetooth API in j2me?

Tags: java-me, bluetooth

I am planning to implement a server using Bluetooth API using J2ME. I want multiple clients to be able to connect to it at the same time but I could not find much on the NET.

```
 UUID uuid = new UUID("1101", false);
    String SurveyAnswer="";
    //Create the service url
    String connectionString = "btspp://localhost:" + uuid + ";name=xyz";
    //open server url
    StreamConnectionNotifier streamConnNotifier = (StreamConnectionNotifier) Connector.open(connectionString);
    //Wait for client connection
   System.out.println("\nServer Started. Waiting for clients to connect...");
   while(true){
     StreamConnection connection = streamConnNotifier.acceptAndOpen();    
    }
```

How do I modify these codes in order for it to work as a multi client server?

Comment: What's wrong with the code as it stands?

Comment: Only one peer is able to connect at a time..When a peer wants to connect to the service and another peer's request is being processed, the former has to wait until its request is processed.

Answer (score 0):

That's a standard problem. When the StreamConnection connection = streamConnNotifier.acceptAndOpen(); returns you have to spawn a Thread which uses the connection. The main Thread then reenters the accept and waits for next connection.

```
 UUID uuid = new UUID("1101", false);     String SurveyAnswer="";     
 //Create the service url     
 String connectionString = "btspp://localhost:" + uuid + ";name=xyz";
 //open server url
 StreamConnectionNotifier streamConnNotifier = (StreamConnectionNotifier) 
     Connector.open(connectionString);
 //Wait for client connection
 System.out.println("\nServer Started. Waiting for clients to connect...");
 while(true){
   StreamConnection connection = streamConnNotifier.acceptAndOpen();      
   System.out.println("Client connected starting communication");
   new CommunicationThread(connection).start();   
 }
```

In the class CommunicationThreads run method you can then get the streams and communicate.

Comment: Does your CommunicationThread extend Thread? start() belongs to Thread